# Why is my Observable only sending a message to the most recent subscriber

Tags: angularjs, coffeescript, rxjs

I have 2 Angular (1.6.4) components and a service. The service creates 2 observables like this (coffeescript)...

```
// In service constructor
@observable = Rx.Observable.create (source) =>
      source.next(123)
@observable2 = Rx.Observable.create (source) =>
      @observer = source
$timeout => 
      @observer.next(345)
, 1000
```

In my controllers I have these lines

```
//Component 1
service.observable.subscribe (v) => console.log('consumer A1: ' + v)
service.observable2.subscribe (v) => console.log('consumer A2: ' + v)
//Component 2
service.observable.subscribe (v) => console.log('consumer B1: ' + v)
service.observable2.subscribe (v) => console.log('consumer B2: ' + v)
```

I would expect to see 4 console logs but instead I see 3 (A1, B1, B2). Why is it then when I call from outside only the last subscribe gets called but when it is inside both get called? Is there a way to have the second example call both (preferably as an Observable and not a Subject)?

If I do use a Subject everything works as expected but I am still curious why it doesn't work as I would expect with an observable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your observable2 is taking the subscriber and storing it in a variable (`@observer`) each time something subscribes.  So the 2nd subscription (`B2`) is replacing the value in the variable.

It is hard to say what the correct way to rewrite the 2nd observer should be because it isn't clear what your goal is.  A Subject can certainly work.  `Observable.timer` might also work, depending on your goal.

The Observable.timer way would be:

```
@observable2 = Observable.timer(1000);
```

Anything that subscribes to that would get an event 1 second after it subscribed.

Comment: I see so I think the part I was missing is that every time someone subscribes it creates a new observer. That was the part I was missing.